# Поиск тега по значению атрибута меньшего чем заданное число

Tags: jquery

Возможно ли jquery запросом в DOM модели найти нужный набор тегов у которых определённый атрибут меньше заданного значение например:

```
...
<div class="test"><i value="1"></i><i value="2"></i><i value="3"></i></div>
...
$(".test i[value<=2]").addClass("test_2");
...
```

Данная конструкция ошибок не вызывает но и к нужному результату не приводит (у `<i>` с `value==1` и `value==2` добавить класс `test_2`)
В доках jquery не нашёл что можно делать `'<='` но и опровержение этому тоже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используя статью: [Создаем собственные селекторы для jQuery](http://jquerylist.ru/tutorials/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities.html)

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
   valueLessThen: function(el, index, meta) {
      if(!meta[3]) {return false;}
      return parseInt($(el).attr('value')) < parseInt(meta[3]);
   }
});

$('i:valueLessThen(3)').addClass('test_2')
```

если чуть больше поработать над этой темой, можно сделать более универсальный селектор

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".test i").each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('value')<=2){
    $(this).addClass("test_2");
  }
});
```

Лучше в таких случаях не мудрить, имхо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я понял идею, но val() судя по поведению работает только на :input, так что поправьте в ответе на attr('value'). И академически интересно что будет быстрее: each или query? И хочется узнать именно ответ на вопрос - возможно ли это сделать через query или нет.

Comment: Поправил. Думаю, что в большинстве случаев разницу в скорости вы не заметите. =) Есть множество гораздо более тормознутых моментов в скриптах.