# Добавить класс всем элементам, после текущего

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если есть возможность, подскажите как решить несложную задачу.
Есть разметка:

```
<div data-index="1" class="item"></div>
<div data-index="2" class="item"></div>
<div data-index="3" class="item"></div>
<div data-index="4" class="item"></div>
```

Необходимо при ховере на элемент добавить класс тем элементам, у которых data-index > data-index текущего элемента.

Т.е. если навели на первый элемент, добавить класс "active" к 2,3 и 4 элементу, если навели на 2ой элемент, то добавить класс только для 3го и четвёртого, и т.д.

```
$(function() {
    var items = $('.item');

    items.hover(function() {
        var currentItem = $(this).data("item");

        ????
    });
});
```

Comment: А что получается вместо этого?

Comment: Найдено решение благодаря похожей теме из вопроса "Поиск тега по значению атрибута меньшего чем заданное число".

Comment: Не надо править вопрос убирая саму ошибку, это делает не релевантными уже данные ответы, и сам текст вопроса, в котором есть _записать код заместо "????"_ а в предоставленном коде уже нет `????`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Топорный вариант:

```
items.each((item)=>{ if(item.data('index')*1 > currentItem*1) item.addClass('active'); else item.removeClass('active');}
```

Есть ещё вариант одной query через вычислители jquery вроде, что-то типа

```
$('.items:indexGrow('+currentItem+')').addClass('active');
```

и определить вычислитель ':indexGrow', но сейчас не помню как это точно делать :-)

**P.S**

Вот, точно, сам задавал подобный вопрос пять лет назад:

[Поиск тега по значению атрибута меньшего чем заданное число.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120208/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)

Comment: Большое спасибо, нашёл ответ благодаря Вашей теме "Поиск тега по значению атрибута меньшего чем заданное число". Решением оказалось :

            $(".item").each(function(){
              if($(this).data('item') > currentItem){
                $(this).addClass("active");
              }
            });